# How to make communication between 2 diifferent iframe HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, iframe

I'm using ruby on rails to develop web app and I have 2 HTML iframe from different file and folder, however, both of them are display at the same link. How can I make them communicate to each other, for example, when I click in the element form iframe 1 and I want the referenced information will be shown at iframe 2?

Answer (score 0):

you can use like

```
parent.frames['iframe1'].yourfunction();
```

Comment: can it make 2 iframes understand each other because those are from 2 diffenrent file and folder ?

Comment: yes of domain are the same then then you can call each other js functions

Answer (score 0):

If both of the iframes are under the same domain you can use also parent-child communication via `window.postMessage`. 
Here more details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Hope this can help